# How to check for "delta" argument like "+10"

Tags: shell-script, arguments

I want to pass a numeric value to a bash script, which could be either an absolute integer value (0-100) or a relative "delta" like "+10" or "-50".

How would I parse `$1` to check for `+` or `-` and grab the remaining text as a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on @frams's idea, we can make the answer shorter:

```
sign=${1//[[:digit:]]}
value=${1//[^[:digit:]]}
```

`${1//[[:digit:]]}` deletes digit part of `${1}`

`${1//[^[:digit:]]}` deletes non-digit part of `${1}`

ref: Advanced Bash Scripting Guide by Mendel Cooper

Comment: Nice! Works with "+10" as well as "10+" etc.

Comment: Of course it would also catch "1+0"

Comment: @DavidZ In this case, I think we could use `if [[ $1 -eq $1 ]]; then echo ${1//[^0-9]} ; fi` to make sure $1 is a number, i.e. 10, +10, or -10

Answer (score 4):

You can use `${var:offset:length}` to extract part of a variable and compare the result of this as needed. If you omit the `length` part the remainder of the string starting from offset will be taken.

```
if [[ ${1:0:1} == "+" ]]; then
    is_negative=false
    is_delta=true
    arg=${1:1}
elif [[ ${1:0:1} == "-" ]]; then
    is_negative=true
    is_delta=true
    arg=${1:1}
else
    is_negative=false
    is_delta=false
    arg=$1
fi
```

Comment: Code snippet is not a very good quality answer, I suggest to use also human language.

Answer (score 2):

There is a trick to do this

```
sign=`echo $1|sed -e 's/[0-9]//g'`;
 num=`echo $1|sed -e 's/[+-]//g'`;
echo $sign;  # gets + - or empty
echo $num;   # gets the number
```

`sed -e 's/[0-9]//g'` delete all digits, + - remains

`sed -e 's/[+-]//g'` delete + -, digits remains

works for all cases including 0, +0, -0.

Answer (score 1):

With posix shell

```
unset -v sign value
value="${1#[-+]}"
if [ "$value" -eq "$value" 2> /dev/null ];then
  [ "$1" != "$value" ] && sign="${1%$value}"
  echo "sign = $sign value = $value"
else
  echo "not a number $1"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

For Bash, I would use the syntax `${var:offset:length}` like in [patrix's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/414117), but with another approach.  You should compute your base value before.

For example (the value is relative to the current hour):

```
[[ "$1" =~ ^[+-]?(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$ ]] || exit 2

base="$(date +"%-H")"

case "${1:0:1}" in
"+")
    value="${1:1}"                                                                                                                 
    value=$((base + value))
    ;;
"-")
    value="${1:1}"                                                                                                                 
    value=$((base - value))
    ;;
*)
    value="$1"
    ;;
esac

((value < 0)) || ((value > 23)) && exit 2

echo "Task planned for ${value}h"
```